# JavaScript adding unexpected window.history entries

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, history

When I load a certain page on my site in a new tab, I noticed the back button was enabled. This shouldn't be the case considering it's the first page of a new tab. In fact when I click & hold on the back button I see that the page location I'm on is duplicated between 1 and 10 times in the history. I also see multiple entries added to the history when doing a single refresh on this page.

Notes:

- Disabling JavaScript causes the issue to go away.
- Using 'window.onpopstate', I noticed this function fires before the browser history is modified. But I've read elsewhere that this method is called on any page load on chrome.
- This issue happens on Chrome & Firefox, and IE
- The number of times the page id duplicated to the history range from 1 to 10 times.

Related Resource Links:

- http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#event-popstate
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: This is really vague.  Is there a particular part of your code causing the problem?

Comment: It looks like it was an issue related to iFrames. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976094/iframe-causing-back-button-issues